# Adding someone on LinkedIn after I interviewed with them, but didn't get the job.

Tags: interviewing, linkedin, networking

I recently attended two interviews for a position, a general ‘meet each other’' interview, and then a technical interview.

Both interviews seemed to go well, friendly and amicable. However, I was informed that while I was a good cultural fit, I didn't have the technical skills for the position (I don't have working experience with the technology they’re using, just what I've learnt in my spare time). They said to keep in touch if any positions come up.

The question is—would it be appropriate to add one of the interviewers on LinkedIn? Is this what LinkedIn is used for?

Answer (score 5):

You say this:

> They said to keep in touch if any positions come up.

And this:

> Is this what Linked In is used for?

LinkedIn is good for keeping in professional contact with professional contacts. So it is 100% appropriate. But it’s your judgement on how well your interview went which should dictate whether you add them to LinkedIn or not.

Answer (score -1):

"Both interviews seemed to go well, friendly and amicable" Almost every interview goes well, is friendly and amicable. They don't want some candidate to get unhinged during the interview because who knows what happens next. No matter what they eventually decide to do with your candidacy, they want you to make a quick, clean, no fuss, no muss exit out of the building after the interview is over.

There's nothing to stop you from asking one of the interviewers to link with you. Linkedin is used for many purposes and you may want to become familiar with the different features of it.

Comment: Is the RTFM really necessary here?

Comment: Yea, ending a perfectly ok answer with a rude acronym like that is FUBAR

Comment: Maybe it goes well with IT in general: SNAFU